# How to force a page to be odd

Tags: page-numbering, header-footer

How can one trick LaTeX to believe that a given page is odd instead of even?

Or alternatively call the odd-page header in a previously defined pagestyle?

```
\thispagestyle{Somehow-define-that-i-want-odd-page-style-from-"fancy"}
```

The document class used is `book`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very simple — just insert `\cleardoublepage`, which will start a new odd page (inserting a blank page before if necessary).

Some structuring commands in the `book` document class insert `\cleardoublepage` by themselves if the `openright` option (on by default) is enabled, such as:

```
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\backmatter
\part
\chapter
…
```

Comment: It seems that in some situations, it doesn't... still trying to figure why